# Unique IdentityColumn value depended on another column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have following properties and FluentApi annotations :

```
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    builder.Property(s => s.TenantId).IsRequired();
    builder.Property(x => x.Identifier)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .UseIdentityColumn();

    builder.HasIndex(x => x.Identifier).IsUnique(false);
    builder.HasIndex(nameof(MyPOCOModel.TenantId), nameof(MyPOCOModel.Identifier)).IsUnique();
```

I want to get something like :

```
tenantid                              |  identifier
419AF43A-0BC9-48DC-8227-8443F605BD04  |  1
419AF43A-0BC9-48DC-8227-8443F605BD04  |  2
419AF43A-0BC9-48DC-8227-8443F605BD04  |  3
7D8FA14B-3269-4327-BD6A-65001EA50365  |  1
7D8FA14B-3269-4327-BD6A-65001EA50365  |  2
```

I want to generate unique column `Identifier` (autoincrement) depended to `TenantId` scope. I don't want to use custom generator like `HasValueGenerator<T>`

Comment: You cannot as that's not how `IDENTITY` columns work. Those are unique across the table, not scoped. One way or another this requires custom logic, whether it's on the C# end or in a stored procedure somewhere.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yep I know about how IDENTITY columns work. But ValueGeneratedOnAdd does not work without IDENTITY columns. I don't like stored procedures, I'm trying to work around it.

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure, necessarily, but custom logic involving SQL to select the next value is unavoidable, and getting this correct in the face of concurrency is not trivial -- it's exactly the sort of code that best belongs in an sproc if you want to separate concerns. Alternatively, if you only need this number on retrieval, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenantid ORDER BY ...)` to generate it on the fly (or whatever the EF equivalent is) but of course this number would not be stable if rows are inserted or deleted.